# Web scraping python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Необходимо спарсить название ютуб канала через ссылку.
Вот код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

driver = BeautifulSoup(get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCapfEzadQamVtUXGp1oDSwQ').text, 'lxml')
print(driver.head.title.text)
```

Возникает проблема, что в одном случае результат:

Шахматы online Обучение - YouTube

В другом:

YouTube

Как пофиксить эту проблему без использования костылей?

Comment: Воспользоваться `API`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [`YouTube Data API`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


API_KEY = '...'
CHANNEL_ID = 'UCapfEzadQamVtUXGp1oDSwQ'


params = {
    'key': API_KEY,
    'id': CHANNEL_ID,
    'part': 'snippet',
}
d = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels', params=params).json()

title = d['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
print(title)
```

***stdout:***

```py
Шахматы online Обучение
```